# How do I remove the "did you mean..." feature in the shell?

Tags: bash

When I fail to type correctly a command, for example:

```
luca@mostro:~$ sido
No command 'sido' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo-ldap' (universe)
 Command 'sid' from package 'tendra' (universe)
sido: command not found
```

The command interpreter try to guess what program I wanted to run. This is very annoying to me (I associate it to google behavior).

Is it possible to remove this feature? And how?

I supposed that it were setup in my local `~/.bashrc`, but the fast-check failed miserably...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove command-not-found
sudo mv /usr/share/command-not-found /usr/share/command-not-found.bak
```

You need to restart your shell for the change to take affect.

Comment: Don't move things around under `/usr` that belong to packages. In the case of `/usr/share/command-not-found`, that directory belongs to the `command-not-found-data` package. Now your package manager will be confused.

Answer (score 19):

```
sudo apt-get remove command-not-found command-not-found-data
```

Contrary to the other answer, you should **not** manually move things around under `/usr` unless you're trying to defenestrate your package manager.

Comment: There is no package 'command-not-found-data' in 22.04.

Comment: For 22.04 `sudo apt remove command-not-found` does the trick. In `/etc/bash.bashrc` there is a check for `/usr/lib/command-not-found`. When removed, change is instantly effective.

Answer (score 14):

Both of the **other answers assume root**, *and* that you want to remove it globally for the system.  If you just want to ***disable this for a single user*** (eg, your own unprivileged account), you can simply do:

```
unset command_not_found_handle
```

either on the command line for the current shell, or in their `.bashrc`

The feature is typically enabled **globally** by defining `command_not_found_handle` in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, so could also be disabled there by default, while still leaving the package available for a power user to define the function and *enable* the feature in their own account.