# How to enable suggestion if command not found ("did you mean..." feature) in "bash" shell?

Tags: command-line, bash

Similar to this question:
[How do I remove the "did you mean..." feature in the shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146508/how-do-i-remove-the-did-you-mean-feature-in-the-shell)

When mistyping a command you get something like:

```
root@pc:~# sido
No command 'sido' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo-ldap' (universe)
sido: command not found
root@pc:~#
```

Is there a shell plugin for linux or ubuntu which recommends the first guess and I just have to press enter?

So it should be like:

```
root@pc:~# sido
No command 'sido' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo-ldap' (universe)
sido: command not found
Did you mean 'sudo' [Y/n]?
```

So I just need to press enter and the sudo command is executed instead of sido.

Comment: is the `zsh` shell an option for you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're willing to switch shells, `zsh` offers this without plugins:

```
$ setopt correct 
$ sido -i
zsh: correct 'sido' to 'sudo' [nyae]? 
y
[sudo] password for muru:
```

From the [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_16.html#IDX211):

> `CORRECT` turns on spelling correction for commands, and the
>   `CORRECTALL` option turns on spelling correction for all arguments.
>
> ```
> % setopt correct
> % sl
> zsh: correct `sl' to `ls' [nyae]? y
> % setopt correctall
> % ls x.v11r4
> zsh: correct `x.v11r4' to `X.V11R4' [nyae]? n
> /usr/princton/src/x.v11r4 not found
> % ls /etc/paswd
> zsh: correct to `/etc/paswd' to `/etc/passwd' [nyae]? y
> /etc/passwd
> ```
>
> If you press `y` when the shell asks you if you want to correct a
>   word, it will be corrected. If you press `n`, it will be left alone.
>   Pressing `a` aborts the command, and pressing `e` brings the line up
>   for editing again, in case you agree the word is spelled wrong but you
>   don't like the correction.

Comment: Nice, this looks good! Will look at it. Is there another solution using the standard /bin/bash?

Comment: @SailAvid not that I know of. Bash only offers correction for paths (for use with `cd`: `cdspell`, or directories in general: `dirspell`).

Comment: `sudo apt-get install sl`/`brew install sl`

Comment: @kenorb hell no! I find `sl` more annoying than useful.

Answer (score 22):

If zsh isn't an option, take a look at [thefuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck)

It can be installed with:

```
sudo pip install thefuck
```

One of the examples in the readme is almost exactly what you're requesting:

```
➜ puthon
No command 'puthon' found, did you mean:
  Command 'python' from package 'python-minimal' (main)
  Command 'python' from package 'python3' (main)
zsh: command not found: puthon

➜ fuck
python
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:08:17)
...
```

It also does some other handy stuff like:

```
➜ apt-get install vim
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

➜ fuck
sudo apt-get install vim
[sudo] password for nvbn:
Reading package lists... Done
...
```

or

```
➜ git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master


➜ fuck
git push --set-upstream origin master
Counting objects: 9, done.
...
```

Comment: This is Awesome!

Comment: [Doesn't help](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck/commit/5de020bccd2a7ea6ba34087fef06f08df09ced41), as I usually use `sl` to punish my-self in order to cure my bad habit of mistyping